# How to respond to professor if he wants me but I need responses from other professors?

Tags: phd, application

I just started my PhD application. I read some papers and wrote letters to professors that I want to work with. I started getting some feedback from different professors. Many of them will schedule a meeting with me. My first question is what is the most appropriate response if some professors(first or second professors that scheduled a meeting for me) would like to have me in their group after the meeting but I still want to wait for other professors' interview and their responses?

My second question is that how do I know the professor is a good advisor? I wrote some letters to their PhD students but what other aspects should I focus on? Some students told me that the PhD students may not make a subjective answer since they don't want to get into trouble. I think the personality and how the professor organizes his research group are very important because I need to stay with him for a long time. The second question is related to the first since I don't want to make casual decisions for the professor.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you ask a PhD student how happy they are with their advisor and they say "I better not say anything, I don't want to get into trouble", that's already an orange-to-red sign that things aren't exactly great.

Comment: What country? In the US, even if you get a positive response, there are still a lot of steps between now and making a decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question: the best you can do is be honest and say at the interviews that you are exploring several options. If you get proposed a position straight away, just answer that you need some time to consider the offer and explore all your possibilities (do not ghost people, though). This applies to a PhD position as well as any other position, inside or outside academia. If a professor gets offended by you asking for some time to think it through ("you should be honored to work with me"-kind of reasoning) well, maybe you don't want to work with them.

For the second question: you don't know. Asking PhD students how they like working with their professor is actually a good idea - in my experience they would answer honestly. Maybe they won't say their professor is terrible, but normally you can read between the lines. You write "I don't want to make casual decisions for the professor". The problem is that any professor has a different style of supervising graduate students. My advisor would see me once every one/two months because he believed that graduate students should carry on their own research independently. In those meetings, he would steer me in the direction he believed to be the right one, without forcing me to take a specific path. I liked this approach, and at the end of my PhD studies I became a more-or-less independent researcher. Other colleagues (few of them) did not and would have preferred to have weekly or biweekly meetings, which other professors do. I would have hated it and would have felt babysitted, micromanaged.

You have to understand what style would suit you best, and ask maybe in the interviews how the professor organizes meetings, how involved they get into technical details.